# Как с помощью Jsoup или Gson спарсить картинки с сайта?

Tags: android, jsoup

Добрый день.
У меня есть андроид приложение, в котором я собираюсь разместить картинки с одного сайта.

Знаю, что для парсинга подходят Jsoup/Gson.

Картинки на сайте хранятся в блоке div (типа итем лист), в котором вложены другие div'ы, в которых в аттрибуте style (background-image) прописан url к картинке.

Пример:

```
<div class="itemlist">
<div class="pic1"> <div style="background-image: url("путь к картинке")"></div>
<div class="pic2"> <div style="background-image: url("путь к картинке")"> </div>
<div class="pic3"> <div style="background-image: url("путь к картинке")"> </div>
...
<div class="picN"> <div style="background-image: url("путь к картинке")"> </div>
</div>
```

Если тут есть, кто умеет парсить такие вещи с помощью вышеупомянутых библиотек, подскажите, пожалуйста, как парсить эти картинки?

И еще вопрос, нужно ли для парсинга с помощью этих библиотек создавать отдельный AsyncTask?

Comment: 1. GSON Не подходит, он парсит JSON, а не HTML. 2. выбираете все интересующие вас элементы по вашему критерию, берете к каждого style, и у style - background-image

Comment: С помощью Jsoup такое можно сделать?

Comment: можно. И использование AsyncTask зависит от реализации.

Comment: Реализация такая: у меня есть Recyclerview, в который будут загружаться картинки. Картинок может быть сколь угодное множество.